# html <img> tag shows gif's but doesnt show jpg's

Tags: html, image, firefox, jpeg, gif

I got a small problem with html img tags.

I got a lot of banners on my website, but for some reason firefox only shows the gif's and not the jpg's.

I have tried changing to source to the files but that didn't help much.

anyone out here knows what to do ?

[JsFiddle example of the images](http://jsfiddle.net/dheitinga/5r7rrtkx/)

```
<!-- i didnt use the original links to the website and banners since they are
adult websites. -->

<!-- This one will work since its a gif -->

<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="468" height="60" src="http://fakesite.com/Upload/Banners/banner1.jpg" /></a>

<!-- This one doesnt -->
<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img border="0" width="468" height="60" src="http://fakesite.com/Upload/Banners/banner2.gif" /></a>
```

Comment: can you post your code and recreate your problem in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Does it happen in other browsers?l

Comment: Can you show your code and the name of the images on which the problem occurs?

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dheitinga/5r7rrtkx/) @atmd

Comment: @PM77-1 just in firefox. chrome and IE are working properly

Comment: What exactly are we supposed to gain with that fiddle? Did you try running FF in safe mode with all the plugins disabled?

Comment: @j08691 well thats exactly what i have on my webpage, and atmd asked me to recreate my problem, and ill give that a go now

Comment: @j08691 that did work, but how do i find out what the problem is?

Comment: What worked, safe mode? If so, disable all your plugins and then re-enabled them one at a time to see which one is the culprit.

Comment: firefox, as far as I've ever been aware, displays gif's fine. so the error must be somewhere else. however we have nothing to go on to find a solution

Comment: after going into safe mode, then restarting again normally, it works fine, so thanks @j08691.

Answer (score 0):

Going into safe mode, then restarting normally, the jpg's were showing like they're supposed to. thanks @j08691